# IF statement in SELECT in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select columns IF `workspace.assigned_to = NULL` ELSE don't select anything.

```
SELECT workspace.*, projects.*,
  CASE 
    WHEN workspace.assigned_to != NULL 
    THEN users.user_id,users.first_name, users.last_name 
   END FROM workspace
INNER JOIN projects ON workspace.workspace_id = projects.project_id 
INNER JOIN users ON workspace.assigned_to = users.user_id
WHERE project_id=:project_id
```

Comment: What about using `WHERE workspace.assigned_to != NULL`?

Comment: I need to get all results. Even results with `worksapce.assigned_to = NULL`.

Comment: But in your question you said you do not want rows when that column is null. Isn't that contradictory?

Comment: I meant select columns. If `worksapce.assigned_to != NULL` then select `some field, some field`

Comment: You can't have variable number of columns per row. What you can do is either perform two queries, or perform single query with the `WHERE` clause and filter out the columns by iterating through the rows with a programming language.

Comment: Hmm yes. I also have another concept in mind. if `assigned_to = NULL` then `first_name = " ", last_name = " "`

Comment: @user3284463: then write 3 `CASE`s for each field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT workspace.*, projects.*,
  users.user_id,users.first_name, users.last_name
FROM workspace
INNER JOIN projects ON workspace.workspace_id = projects.project_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON workspace.assigned_to = users.user_id
WHERE project_id=:project_id
```

LEFT JOIN means we join users by assigned_to but if it's null the users' valuea are nulls

Comment: Wow, Thanks! really awesome thinking